# Prevent Copying from a Range of Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to protect a range of cells in Excel, that I don't want another user to copy text from. Is it possible?

I did have a look at this other question: [Locking cell range in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/492191/locking-cell-range-in-excel), but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: "protect a range of cells" isn't the best title, most will assume it's about preventing change, a better title might be "Can copy from a range of cells be prevented in Excel"

Comment: Thanks @Tyson :) Is that better?

Comment: @Tyson You can make edits and earn reputation points for each approved suggested edit. We need all the editing help we can get around here.

Comment: Much better =] The problem of course is how the word "protect" is used in excel. @Kevdog777 I edit occasionally, but I'd never re-title someone's brand new question.

Comment: Why give the information to the user if you don't want them to have it?

Comment: Because it is a check spreadsheet, that I want the user to look at a column and write the check next to it - but not to copy and paste it. i.e. Cell Range A has the original data and Cell Range B is for the user to input data. So ideally they should match up

Comment: Why can't they copy it? What if they take a picture or screenshot? What's the goal here?

Comment: I am a tester, and this is what we do. If the user (another tester) copies the cells and pastes it, then surely it is not an accurate test?

Comment: Then they aren't doing their **job**. You can prevent this via VBA, but they could just turn off macros or remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up VBA and put this in the the sheet module -

```
Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal target As Range)
If Not Intersect(target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Don't click")
    Range("B1").Select
End If
End Sub
```

As long as macros are enabled and you lock the ability to edit them, they won't be able to select anything in column A.

OR

select your range, right click, format cells. Go to protection and click locked.

Then go to review and protect sheet and unselect "select locked cells"

Then put a password on the book.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have VBA on my Excel. I was hoping it would be something within Excel (similar to how you can `Protect` sheets, etc.).

Comment: @Kevdog777 see the second part of my answer